# Javascript before leaving a page except when a element by class or ID is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that works great keeping a user from leaving a page before saving changes. What I need to do though is not display the message when the user clicks a button by ID or class name

So in this situation, if the user tries to refresh the page, go back in history or whatever the message will appear, except I do not want the message to appear when the user clicks on the save button. Is this possible?

**HTML**

```
<button id="save">Save Changes</button>
or
<button class="save">Save Changes</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?';
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
</script>
```

Comment: Is the button inside a form element?

Answer (score 0):

add an event listener on the `window` for `beforeunload`, and remove it when the button is clicked

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wub8a3y6/1/)

```js
function goodbye(e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?';
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', goodbye);

document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', goodbye);
});
```

```html
<button id="save">Save Changes</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your buttons are inside of a form element which makes them automatically submit when clicked. Try adding `type="button"` to your buttons:
`<button class="save" type="button">Save Changes</button>`

Then use Javascript to submit the form when the buttons are clicked.